# Clear a particular line of a file through bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I want to clear the contents of a particular line in a file.
I could delete the line by using sed:

```
sed -i "${linenumber}d" filename.txt
```

But I dont want the line to be deleted. I want the line to stay with no content.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Sure:

```
sed -i "${linenumber} s/.*//" filename.txt
```

The `${linenumber}` specifies which line to work on, the delete command (`d`) in your sed script can be replaced by any other command, here the substitution command (`s/pattern/replacement/`).